# How to compare POSIX ACLs?

Tags: c, posix, acl

Given two `acl_t` values, how do I compare them? That is, I need a way to find out if one `acl_t` has more or less entries than the other, or if the given `acl_entry_t` contains different set of permissions than the other one.

Linux does have non-standard `acl_cmp` function. What I need is basically a POSIX-compliant variant of this function.

The only idea I've come up with so far is comparing ACL's textual representations:

```
strcmp(acl_to_text(acl1), acl_to_text(acl2))
```

Any more performant solutions?

Comment: Or you compare them "by hand": going through both lists to check their length; searching the other list for each value in the first list.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie all of the `acl_t`, `acl_entry_t`, `acl_permset_t` and other are opaque types. I can't look inside them and there seem to be no API to get the information out.

Comment: Did you look at [what `acl_cmp` does](https://git.savannah.nongnu.org/cgit/acl.git/tree/libacl/acl_cmp.c?id=40c190dc1f6630054d7d2f850a0b9fb10c7bbcb1)?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Yes I did. Since it is a part of `libacl`, it access the inner parts of all the structures. I can't just do `p1_obj_p->whatever`.

Comment: It looks like ACLs in POSIX [were abandoned as a draft](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/489820/217726), so they're not part of POSIX and not really standardized at all. What specifically do you want to support other than Linux?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica FreeBSD, for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `acl_t` is an opaque type, the client code can't implement `acl_cmp`. Moreover, using `strcmp(acl_to_text(acl1), acl_to_text(acl2))` also can't be relied on, because ACL's may be equivalent, but sorted in different order.

I came to conclusion that this function along with some others should've ended up in the standard, but unfortunate way of events resulted in its abandoned state.